# wordpress website shows two different interface for users side and admin side

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[this is the issue I'm facing. on my admin side, I change the whole content but still, it's showing the earlier style for end users. whatever I change on the admin side It shows the same earlier styles means the previous content and design, I'm facing this issue after changing the server of my website so I'm not getting the actual problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljtXl.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question that is more likely to get answered, and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a cookies problem. Try to clear out your cookies and empty your browser history... also try an hard refresh after that with cmd+maj+R on mac. gl.

Comment: but I'm using Windows what will be the command for a hard refresh?

Comment: Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key